# Where does the peek snap locate its finished file?

Tags: gif

trying the snap on Bionic Beaver and I cannot locate where it is located.

Do you thnk someone could help me sometime in terms of a  sysfolder?

Comment: Well, first of all welcome to askubuntu. Whether somebody can help you prior to July depends among others on the quality of your question. Setting a time frame for volunteers, might come over a bit rude. It would have helped if you included what peek is. If you mean the GIF recorder please note that the snap is no longer supported https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/03/peek-snap-app-discontinued .Normally peek prompts for a path to save when finishing as can be seen here https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/peek-desktop-gif-screen-recorder-linux.

Comment: /user/392858/bruni Just looking for the folder that the gif is saved into in terms of a file on linux ?

Comment: Don't you get to choose a path when the file is saved? As in the second link I posted?

Comment: After much [mucking around](https://photos.smugmug.com/My-First-Gallery/i-HbRZzsL/0/b6def9e2/S/Peek%202018-06-29%2016-30-S.gif) I have realized it saved the .gif to Pictures in the home folder.

Comment: I;m glad you got it sorted. Self answering is encouraged here. Feel free to do so.